# Flywaydb 32 bit version

Tags: flyway

Hi we want to implement flyway db in our organisation.
I need to confirm if 32 bit version is available for download.
if yes pl's share the link as i can't find one on flyway official site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

flyway itself is a java application. so it need a JRE (java runtime environment) to run.

The website offers a package that comes with in integrated jre - but that is the 64 bit version: https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/download

But you can just download the .zip distribution without the JRE and use the 32 bit JRE from oracle: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

That will work.